# Custom CollectionView Layout

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I want to make a custom cell like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "1")
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "2")
        } else {
            cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "3")
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: screenWidth / 2, height: screenWidth)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            return CGSize(width: screenWidth / 2, height: screenWidth / 2 - 20)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: screenWidth / 2, height: screenWidth / 2 - 20)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't know which iOS version you were in, but from iOS 12.0 we have something called ```UICollectionViewLayout``` class which can be subclassed that can achive this type of layout. Please see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/layouts/customizing_collection_view_layouts

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't really know how to fix your issue, I know a third party library that exactly does what you want. [Check this out.](https://github.com/gringoireDM/FBLikeLayout)

You can use it to get your desired result or perhaps look into the code and see how it is done.

P.S. The code is in Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.